# How can I create a alert through SharePoint REST API?

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api, alert

Is there any REST API which can create the alert on a SharePoint List?

We have a customized website which user can view files on SharePoint, but when user want to subscribe to a folder or file changes, I couldn't find any REST API to do so. Currently user can only go to SharePoint site, select the file or folder and click "Alert me" to create a new alert. Can I do this for user through a REST API call?

I found there are some information of [CSOM API](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/16520425-csom-jsom-api-to-manage-sharepoint-list-item-ale), but I can't find any REST API related to alerts.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: @superigno No, I didn't. We don't use built in alert function anymore, instead we implement our own subscription function.

Answer (score 0):

> SharePoint webhooks **enable developers to build applications that subscribe to receive notifications on specific events that occur in SharePoint**. When an event is triggered, SharePoint sends an **HTTP POST payload** to the subscriber. Webhooks are easier to develop and consume than Windows Communication Foundation (**WCF**) services used by **SharePoint Add-in remote event receivers** because webhooks are regular HTTP services **(Web API)**

Check this link : [SharePoint webhook](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/webhooks/overview-sharepoint-webhooks)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also found this webhook when I doing my research, but this is not exactly what I want. If I use webhook method to do the alert function, I have to handle user's subscription by my own. What I really want is to use alert function which is built in SharePoint already.